# Personalization is causing 500 errors for the google bot. How do I fix this?

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I'm running Sitecore 8.1 Original Release, and I've started using contact cards for storing information about my visitors. Two weeks ago I launched a campaign that personalized content based on a previous action that was taken on the website. For example, if someone completed a certain goal, I will display personalized content for them.

I tested the code in all of our environments (sandbox/Dev/Test/UA) and everything worked fine. When I rolled my code to our PRODUCTION environment, the personalization worked fine, however I'm getting server errors (500 error code) when the google bot is trying to access the site. I've figure out that's because Sitecore is identifying the visitor as a bot, and so it's not tracking it. In theory that's great, but now I've got to figure out how to replicate the bot error so I can fix it.

I've tried to replicate the error using the following techniques with no error:

1. Curl the URL simulating the google bot agent
2. Turn off analytics/tracking (by disabling the 2 settings in `Sitecore.xdb.config`).
3. Installed several Chrome extensions to block cookies, simulate user agents, clear all cache, etc.
4. I've removed the google bot agent from the list found in `Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config`, and the error goes away. However, I don't want the google bot to start filling up my analytics reports.

What else can I do to replicate the issue in a non-prod environment so I can find the offending code and fix it?

Comment: There will be a stacktrace in the logs for any 500. I would start there. Also, there's a setting to enable/disable robots detection.

Comment: I had looked for the logs, and didn't find anything..... but then realized that I was looking at the logs from the CM server and not the CD Server. The CD Server has plenty of stuff for me to look at. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll update the post with more information as I have it available.